# Passing parameters from ajax to zend controller

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I have a select dropdown on my index view

```
<select name="level" id= "level" onchange="changeLevel(this)">

            <?php $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>

            <?php if ($level == 1): ?>
                 <option value="1" selected ="selected">Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2" <?php IsSelected($level,2); ?>> Manager</option>
                 <option value="3" <?php IsSelected($level,3); ?>>HR Staff</option>
             <?php elseif ($level == 2): ?>
                 <option value="1" <?php IsSelected($level,1); ?>>Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2" selected ="selected">Manager</option>
                 <option value="3" <?php IsSelected($level,3); ?>>HR Staff</option>
               <?php elseif ($level == 3): ?>
                 <option value="1" <?php IsSelected($level,1); ?>>Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2" <?php IsSelected($level,2); ?>>Manager</option>
                 <option value="3" selected ="selected">HR Staff</option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </select>
```

and I want to update the user level whenever he selects on the dropdown so i use onchange event and i also have this ajax to connect to my controller

```
<script>

    changeLevel = function(level){
            var level_value = level.value; 
            alert(level.value);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/ijm/public/user/level',
            data: { function_name: 'level', 
                function_params: level_value },
            Success: function(result){
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
```

and this is my function in my controller

```
public function levelAction()
    {

        $storage = $this->getAuthService()->getStorage();
        $user = $storage->read();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $level = $request->getPost('level_value');
        echo $level;
            // Check if form values are valid
            $this->getUserTable()->editLevel($user->id, $level);
            $this->redirect()->toRoute('user');
            echo "success";      

    }
```

so in my ajax i pass the function parameters which is the selected level on my dropdown. but the problem is my controller doesn't get the parameter i passed.
What should i do to get the correct parameters i passed from ajax to my controller? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

in you ajax function you send `data: { function_name: 'level', function_params: level_value }`, and as a param name you use `function_params`. In your controller instead of `$level = $request->getPost('level_value');` you need to do `$level = $request->getPost('function_params');` or better to do `$level = $this->_getParam('function_params')`;